# System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

Tags: c#

```
public static int[] CountPositivesSumNegatives(int[] input)
    {
         int[] result = new int[0];
            int[] array = input.Where(d => d < 0).ToArray();
            int[] array2 = input.Where(s => s > 0).ToArray();
            return input.Length == 0 ? input
              : result.Concat(new int[] { array2.Length, array.Sum() }).ToArray();
    }
```

System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
public static int[] CountPositivesSumNegatives(int[] input)
{
    int[] result = new int[0];
    
    if (input !=null && input.Length > 0) {
     
     int[] array = input.Where(d => d < 0).ToArray();
     int[] array2 = input.Where(s => s > 0).ToArray();
     return result.Concat(new int[] { array2.Length, array.Sum() }).ToArray();
    }
    return result;
  
}
```

Comment: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Поправил немного

Comment: Test Failed
  Expected: <empty>
  But was:  null

Comment: Так тогда Попробуйте